# Regular Expression , URL validity problem

Tags: regex

Example link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/**tags**/ruby  
true url

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/**@#dsd**/javascript
  false url

How i check the validity of  only /tags/ part not whole url

IS any one who helps me 
Is anyone give me regular expression for this url part.

How i validate my url as per my condition

Thanks

Comment: I think he wants to validate ONLY that specific part of the URL (only alphabetic characters is my guess)

Comment: Yes my dear you are right also include _,-, etc characters also

Comment: @sachinrathore11, Eton B. I've edited my post. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Whole URL:

```
function isValidURL($url) {
    return preg_match('^(https?|ftp)\:\/\/([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?[a-z0-9+\$_-]+(\.[a-z0-9+\$_-]+)*(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@/&%=+\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?\$', $url);
}
```

Unix Folder names (which is basically anything between the /'s):

```
function isValidPath($url) {
    return preg_match('(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?', $url);
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this will accept strings that are not valid http(s) urls, such as hostnames that don't begin with a letter (`[a-zA-Z]`).

Comment: @eld: That's not technically true. I'm building my own answer, so I'll elaborate there.

Comment: @eldarerathis urls dosn't need to start with a-z. For instance, you have the url `卐.com` (note, this is nothing rasistical, only a sample, and the url dosn't work correctly in every browser, howerver, but the specification it should).

Comment: In what situations are urls like that valid, then? Based on the BNF grammar from the W3C, any url beginning with 'http://' should then need to be followed by a letter: http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt. Unless I'm not reading the grammar correctly, of course.

Comment: @eldareathis: IP addresses. In your link, when defining the parts to a URL, it states that after the optional username/pw, you have "The internet domain name of the host in RFC1037 format (or, optionally and less advisably, the IP address as a set of four decimal digits)".

Answer (score 1):

danyim's answer is accurate, though it might not fit your needs exactly, as noted in the comments. Also, his solution was php-based. From scanning your tag participation, I'm guessing that you'd actually prefer a javascript solution (so I'll provide both!).

First, refactoring his php:

```
function isValidURL($url) {
    $regex = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME 
    $regex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?"; // User and Pass 
    $regex .= "((([a-z][a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3}))|(([12]?[0-9]?[0-9]\.){4}))"; // Host or IP 
    $regex .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?"; // Port 
    $regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path 
    $regex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?"; // GET Query 
    $regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; // Anchor 
    return preg_match($regex, lcase($url));
}
```

Note that I modified the return to perform an lcase operation before checking the url. You could also use a case-insensitive flag on the regex to prevent the need for this. As noted, there are a number of parts to this that may or may not be valid for your use-cases. Specifically, you may not ever have a situation in which you want to accept a url that includes a username/pw, or that is from a static IP. You can modify the regex to exclude whatever parts of the match are never valid by removing the related line. Also, here is a second option for the `//Host or IP` line, to make it host only:

```
    $regex .= "([a-z][a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})"; // Host only
```

And now the same thing in javascript (combined together because js handles regex different than strings...adjustments will be easier to make in the php version and then mimic into here):

```
function isValidURL(url) {
   var regex = /((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?((([a-z][a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3}))|(([12]?[0-9]?[0-9]\.){4}))(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?/i
   return (url.match(regex));
}
```